# Back referencing in XPath

Tags: xpath

The more I learn XPath the more I need back refererencing

For example, when I discovered some information in some of intermediate steps, I sometimes need to use the info later. This problem actually has a   workaround with a little help of ability of predicate expression also to contain XPathes also. The working solution can look something like this

```
/foo/item[@attrtocheck = ../../otheritem[@anotherattr]]
```

But the problem with this approach is that I just evaluate predicate on some criteria and can not have multiple following results based on this. Even if there are many otheritem with the same @anotherattr, I can not collect them. So the better solution would be

```
/foo/item[@attrtocheck]/../../otheritem[@anotherattr=BACKREFERENCING_ATTRTOCHECK_VALUE]
```

but as long as I know it's not possible.

If there's no solution in the standard, maybe there's an extension in some tools/libraties? Actually I implement my own engine and if there's a non-standard syntax already existing, I would adopt it.

**UPDATE**: After Michael Kay comment, more about why I miss the feature

Actually I'm imlementing XPath search for AST (Abstract syntax trees). I'm not the first who try to do this (web search for [Xpath AST]). This kind of searches reveals very strong relations between different parts of the tree. For example,when I found some call in some context (for example inside some other method), I would like to know whether this symbol is introduced as a virtual function and if it is then output it to the results. In this case my first search produces some previously unknown symbol (function name) and I would like to use it in the following sub-pathes (searching class declaration and its keywords). So, back referencing would be very helpful.

I think if it's appliable to AST then there is a possibility to have such relations in other structured data.

Comment: Any such problem can be easily solved (isn't a problem at all) in XPath 2.0. `for $attr in /foo/item[@attrtocheck] return /foo/otheritem[@anotherattr=$attr]`

Comment: Telling us that you really need a feature that isn't there isn't going to help unless you tell us what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I updated the question, explaining more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XQuery you can use `let .. return` to declare temporary variables. Like this:

```
 /foo/item[@attrtocheck]/(let $backreference := @attrtocheck return ../../otheritem[@anotherattr=$backreference])
```

And in XPath 2 you can emulate the let expression with a for loop:

```
 /foo/item[@attrtocheck]/(for $backreference in @attrtocheck return ../../otheritem[@anotherattr=$backreference])
```

Or you can use the for loop as intended and do it without "backreference":

```
 for $value in /foo/item[@attrtocheck]/@attrtocheck  return otheritem[@anotherattr=$value]
```

And in this case since comparisons are existential and you can just use:

```
otheritem[@anotherattr = /foo/item/@attrtocheck]
```

(and btw, I also wrote my own XPath implementation and I have the syntax ((values := /xx/a/@id)[0], /xx/b[@id = $values]) for variable declaration, with := defining the variable, and the ()[0] preventing $values from being in the returned sequence. )

Comment: Isn't your answer more about XQuery?

Comment: Also your variant without for and let is similar to the one I mentioned as not sufficient

Comment: Except the let expression, everything is XPath 2. (although XPath 2 is basically a slightly simplified XQuery).

Comment: I see, found it in the XPath 2 spec

Answer (score 0):

I accepted BeniBela solution (also mentioned by Dimitre Novatchev) although I find that this feature somehow lack the simplicity and expressiveness of the XPath 1.0 abbreviated syntax.

I consider also implementing my own function that back reference previously found values. It would accept negative offset to reference previous steps relatively and positive absolutely (from the start of the expression). So this would end in something like

```
 /foo/item[@attrtocheck]/../../otheritem[@anotherattr=backref(-2)]
```

There's no such function in XPath as I suppose, I will not lose the general syntax and referencing previous steps multiply times during the path would look more expressive than multiple for statements